# Simple interprocess communication

Tags: ipc, ada

I would like to know which functionalities Ada offers to implement a (simple) form of interprocess communication between two running executables (not tasks)? I assume that both executables are written in Ada.

Imagine one executable reading data from a sensor at a regular interval `a` and the other executable is interested in processing those values at a regular interval `b`. I think that the package `Ada.Streams.Stream_IO` could be used to serialize and write the sensor data to a file but I'm not sure how the write (first executable) and read (second executable) operations could be synchronized. Could the pragma `Shared_Passive` be used to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Update: A fast experiment using the pragma `Shared_Passive` was successful.

Comment: The following articles ("Ada Gems") on distributed systems might be of interest to you: [Gem #84](https://www.adacore.com/gems/gem-84), [Gem #85](https://www.adacore.com/gems/gem-85the-distributed-systems-annex-2-distributed-objects), [Gem #87](https://www.adacore.com/gems/gem-87-the-distributed-systems-annex-part-3-mailboxes) and [Gem #90](https://www.adacore.com/gems/gem-90-the-distributed-systems-annex-part-4-dsa-and-c). These articles provide some examples related to the Distributed Systems Annex (annex E) of the Ada RM.

Comment: @Marcello90 could you please elaborate on your solution through an answer that you could accept afterwards. This would mark the question as answered and would provide other devs an easier way to solve their own problem than a mere comment

Comment: @FrédéricPraca Of course. ;)

Answer (score 5):

This is my solution for my own question. I found this [Ada Gem #20](https://www.adacore.com/gems/ada-gem-20) describing the usage of the pragma `Shared_Passive`. The GNAT Reference Manual provides more [detailed information](http://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gnat_rm/html/gnat_rm/gnat_rm/implementation_of_specific_ada_features.html#gnat-implementation-of-shared-passive-packages).

The following source code demonstrates the exchange of randomly generated sensor data between a writer and a sensor program.

File: `memory.ads`

```ada
package Memory is

   pragma Shared_Passive;

   type Sensor_Storage_Type is
      record
         Sequence_Numer : Natural := 0;
         Humidity       : Float   := 0.0;
      end record;

   protected Shared is
      function Read return Sensor_Storage_Type;

      procedure Write (Humidity : Float);
   private
      Current_Value : Sensor_Storage_Type;
   end Shared;

end Memory;
```

File: `memory.adb`

```ada
package body Memory is

   protected body Shared is
      function Read return Sensor_Storage_Type is
      begin
         return Current_Value;
      end Read;

      procedure Write (Humidity : Float) is
      begin
         Current_Value.Sequence_Numer := Current_Value.Sequence_Numer + 1;

         Current_Value.Humidity := Humidity;
      end Write;
   end Shared;

end Memory;
```

File: `sensor_writer.adb`

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Numerics.Float_Random;

with Memory;

procedure Sensor_Writer is
   Generator : Ada.Numerics.Float_Random.Generator;

   package Float_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Float_IO (Num => Float);

   Random_Humidity : Float;
begin
   while True loop
      Random_Humidity := Ada.Numerics.Float_Random.Random (Generator) * 100.0;

      Memory.Shared.Write (Random_Humidity);

      Ada.Text_IO.Put ("Wrote sensor value: ");
      Float_IO.Put (Random_Humidity, Exp => 0);
      Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;

      delay 5.0;
   end loop;
end Sensor_Writer;
```

File: `sensor_reader.adb`

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;

with Memory;

procedure Sensor_Reader is
   Sensor_Value : Memory.Sensor_Storage_Type;
begin
   while True loop
      Sensor_Value := Memory.Shared.Read;

      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Read sensor values:");
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("    Sequence number: " & Sensor_Value.Sequence_Numer'Image);
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("    Humidity: " & Sensor_Value.Humidity'Image);

      delay 1.0;
   end loop;
end Sensor_Reader;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the Annex E can help you, and more accurately, the [E.2.3 Remote Call Interface Library Units](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-E-2-3.html).

Just, keep in mind that not all compilers implement Annexe spec. GNAT does, but for other compiler, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to do IPC between processes is to use good old POSIX IPC such as *semaphores*, *shared memories* and *pipes* as implemented in [*Florist*](http://downloads.dragonlace.net/src/florist-gpl-2017-src.tar.gz) (I did not find *Florist* on Adacore website so I'm wondering if this is still maintained).

The pros :

- Make two programs talking to each other without having a network stack
- Programs can be in different languages
- Standard on POSIX Os

The cons :

- Quite low-level programming
- Requires to do synchronisation by hand using semaphore

The packages to look at in *Florist* are *POSIX.Generic_Shared_Memory*, *POSIX.IO* and *POSIX.Semaphores*.

You will find examples on [Jacob Sparre Andersen's POSIX pages](http://edb.jacob-sparre.dk/Posix_in_Ada/10/)